# Angular UI.router and Anchor Tags

Tags: angularjs, jsp, angular-ui-router, struts

We have a large JSP/Struts website which we are converting page-by-page to Angular.  Some of our pages are pure Angular, and the remaining pages are a combination of Angular / JSP / Struts.

We have a main controller which is instanced and in effect on all pages.

The JSP pages, such as the main landing page, have a "home.jsp" as the "index" page.  Our pure Angular pages have their own "index" page.

```
http://ourBigWebsite/somePage -- JSP / Struts
http://ourBigWebsite/ourNewAngularPages/index.html -- Angular
```

For both URLs, the main controller is running.  We have UI.router referenced as a dependency for the main controller.

We are using $stateProvider but not using $routerProvider.  We have only a couple of states defined for Angular, since we have converted only a couple of pages.

The problem is when we hit an old URL such as:

```
http://ourBigWebsite/somePage#someAnchorLink
```

UI.router is adding a slash and changing it to

```
http://ourBigWebsite/somePage#/someAnchorLink
```

Which breaks the old functionality.  How can we change our $stateProvider state definitions so that the old links do not get changed, but only the pages on

```
http://ourBigWebsite/ourNewAngularPages/index.html
```

are being handled/controlled by UI.router.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on app.js location, where it reside? If you want angular $stateProvider for specific part of your project then move app.js in the root of that part.